# Firebase Hosting REST API: Page not found after successful deploy

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting

I was trying to use Python to deploy sites to Firebase Hosting. I followed [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/api-deploy) guide.

My code seems to be working fine, I'm not getting any errors and I'm getting `200` status codes in the API responses. I'm getting all the same responses as they show in the guide:

```json
# versions.create
200, {
  "name": "sites/xxxxx/versions/bd94931c702c6150",
  "status": "CREATED",
  "config": {
    "headers": [
      {
        "headers": {
          "Cache-Control": "max-age=1800"
        },
        "glob": "**"
      }
    ]
  }
}

# versions.populateFiles
200, {
  "uploadRequiredHashes": [
    "13f7dc725fc6c937322b1614479fdb916f5d27f027fef1bee83c7bc61fc393c6",
    "8529e2e12706f35232fce346d3fe23166b72a8fa029c153533e1139a8cc7b08d",
    "30e3a300bf4c8ab3fc5e3906772c9ccabfcbe18447143edf7ab6c9cb22a18d73"
  ],
  "uploadUrl": "https://upload-firebasehosting.googleapis.com/upload/sites/xxxxx/versions/bd94931c702c6150/files"
}

200 # file1 upload
200 # file2 upload
200 # file3 upload

# versions.patch
200, {
  "name": "sites/xxxxx/versions/bd94931c702c6150",
  "status": "FINALIZED",
  "config": {
    "headers": [
      {
        "headers": {
          "Cache-Control": "max-age=1800"
        },
        "glob": "**"
      }
    ]
  },
  "createTime": "2021-10-01T11:38:24.345049Z",
  "createUser": {
    "email": "firebase-adminsdk-xj8ro@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  },
  "finalizeTime": "2021-10-01T11:38:37.780419Z",
  "finalizeUser": {
    "email": "firebase-adminsdk-xj8ro@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }
}

# releases.create
200, {
  "name": "sites/xxxxx/releases/1633088318665339",
  "version": {
    "name": "sites/xxxxx/versions/bd94931c702c6150",
    "status": "FINALIZED",
    "config": {
      "headers": [
        {
          "headers": {
            "Cache-Control": "max-age=1800"
          },
          "glob": "**"
        }
      ]
    },
    "createTime": "2021-10-01T11:38:24.345049Z",
    "createUser": {
      "email": "firebase-adminsdk-xj8ro@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    "finalizeTime": "2021-10-01T11:38:37.780419Z",
    "finalizeUser": {
      "email": "firebase-adminsdk-xj8ro@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    }
  },
  "type": "DEPLOY",
  "releaseTime": "2021-10-01T11:38:38.665339693Z",
  "releaseUser": {
    "email": "firebase-adminsdk-xj8ro@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }
}
```

(I replaced my site ID with `xxxxx`)

I don't know what the problem is.

Maybe it's due to the way I gzip my files? I do it using the `gzip` module in `Python`.

```py
    for file_name in file_names:
        with open(f"{folder_path}/{file_name}", 'rb') as f_in, gzip.open(f"`{OUTPUT_DIR}/{file_name}.gz", 'wb') as f_out:
            f_out.writelines(f_in)
```

And then I read and upload them like this:

```py
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
            "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
            "Content-Length": "500" 
        }

        f = open(file_path, "rb")
        bytes = f.read()

        r = requests.post(API_ENDPOINT, headers=headers, data=bytes)
```

However, I did notice that in my response to the `versions.patch` call
is missing the following part that is present in the tutorial:

```
  "fileCount": "5",
  "versionBytes": "114951"
```

The tutorial seems to be from 2018, so it could be an API change.

After doing everything like shown in the tutorial I still get Page Not Found error when I go to the URL of my site.

I can add more code if it is needed. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did your issue get resolved?

Comment: Hello, thanks for you effort. I now the principles of StackOverflow. I fixed the problem, it was to do with the upload path of the files. You haven’t read the question. The goal of the project is to deploy your site to Firebase Hosting without ever having to touch the CLI. That’s why I used the Firebase Hosting REST API and your suggestions didn’t help me. I hope you understand, have a nice day.

Comment: Yes I misunderstood your question it seems, thanks for correcting me. However, I have one request from you, can you please post your fix as a solution here so that people encountering this issue know the root cause/

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple reasons for the error you are facing. I am trying to put together possible fixes/workarounds for the error in this single answer for you to analyse and try upon :

1. The step to deploy are as following :
   **STEP 1:**

   ```
   ng build --prod
   ```

   **STEP 2:**

   ```
   firebase init
   ```

   *Are you ready to proceed?* Yes

   *What do you want to use as your public directory? dist/{your-
   application-name}
   *Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)?(y/N)*
   Yes
   *File dist/{your-application-name}/index.html already exists.
   Overwrite?(y/N)* No

   **STEP 3:**

   ```
   firebase deploy --only hosting
   ```

   And if still you are getting the same page just press 'CTRL + F5' it
   will clean the cache.
2. Add a dot before /dist on the public tag "public":
   "./dist/my-app-name" Example of firebase.json :

   ```
   {
     "hosting": {
       "public": "./dist/my-app-name",
       "ignore": [
         "firebase.json",
         "**/.*",
         "**/node_modules/**"
       ],
       "rewrites": [
         {
           "source": "**",
           "destination": "/index.html"
         }
       ]
     }
   }
   ```
3. It may happen that, hosting -> public entry in the firebase.json
   file is not pointing to the directory you built it to. If you're
   building a single-page-app with React, double check you have a
   rewrites entry to redirect all requests to index.html

   ```
   "hosting": {
    "public": "build", 
    "ignore": [ "firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**" ], 
    "rewrites": [
      { "source": "**", 
      "destination": "/index.html"
      } ] }
   ```
4. Add site property to firebase.json to fix this.

   ```
   {
    "hosting": { 
     "site": "my-app-id",
    "public": "app", ... … }
   ```
5. It can also be because the index.html has modified itself when you
   selected "Y" while initializing the firebase. It has basically
   replaced your own index file to this one. Check and replace the
   index file and next time, do not overwrite the index.html file. It
   would work.
6. Activate Firestore for the project and specify the Resource Location
   Id by following [Get started with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart).
7. Try the following as you might have deleted the project in the
   console but the source-code was still referencing it hence error 404
   resource not found.

- Delete .firebaserc file (contains your project alias) located in the
  root of the project
- Run firebase init and link to your project
- Run firebase deploy again

8. Make sure you choose a default storage location for your firebase
   project, then deploy again. In `firebase project > project overview > gear icon > project settings > Default GCP resource location`.
   You can simply go to `Firebase Console > Storage > enable Firebase  Storage`and it may resolve the issue.
9. Please update your installation of firebase-tools to the latest via’
   npm i -g firebase-tools’. Also note that we are not actively testing
   or supporting node versions greater than 10 - if you continue having
   issues, downgrade your version of node to 10 and see if the issue
   remains. You may have the latest version locally  but not globally
   installed. See [Get started: write and deploy your first
   functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) for more details.

Also a little suggestion, go through the fixes/workarounds mentioned above, try them and follow the guide (as it is) without missing out on anything, and if still you are getting Page not Found after successful deployment, please open a public issue [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs).